# Custom function in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to generate next number based on month and year. Is this proper way to do it or can it be done differently?

```
class Foo extends Model
{

    public function getNextNumber()
    {
        $result = DB::select('SELECT COALESCE(MAX(number), 0) + 1 AS number FROM foo AS t2 WHERE MONTH(generated_at) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(generated_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())');

        return head($result)->number;
    }
}
```

When create a new record:

```
$foo = new Foo();

$foo->template = 'template1';
$foo->number = $foo->getNextNumber();
$foo->generated_at = DB::raw('NOW()');

$foo->save();
```

Comment: I would seriously consider storing the month and year as separate entities to make operations easier, even though it duplicates the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query itself is fine as long as you don't have too many records in your table - otherwise I'd follow Joel's suggestion and store current number for given year and month in separate table like
**Numbers(year, month, number)**.

If the Laravel code you provided is something you want to run for every model you create, so I'd suggest using Eloquent model events for that:

```
//Foo.php
protected static function boot() {
  parent::boot();

  static::creating(function($foo) {
    $foo->number = $foo->getNextNumber();
    $foo->generated_at = DB::raw('NOW()');
  });
}
```

You could also make the getNextNumber method static so that you don't need an object to get the next number.